# CK EDITOR 5 check empty area during button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor5

How to check the textarea data is blank in CKEDITOR 5.

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="mlksv();">example</button>
<textarea name="mlkzlk" id="editor" placeholder="my abilities"></textarea>
```

Script Code:

```
ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
.then( editor => {
    console.log( editor );
} )
.catch( error => {
    console.error( error );
} );

function mlksv() {
    var editorgmgm = $('#editor').attr('id');
    var _contents = CKEDITOR.instances.editorgmgm.document.getBody().getText();
    if (_contents == '') {
        alert('null') ;
    }else{
        alert("not null");
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In CKEditor 5, you now have to keep a reference to the instantiated editor.

```
let theEditor; // reference to ckeditor obj
ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
.then( editor => {
    theEditor = editor;
    console.log( editor );
    ...
```

Then, use the [`getData()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/basic-api.html) method to retrieve the content.

```
var _contents = theEditor.getData();
if (_contents == '') {
...
```